# How can I set the variable for the first iteration, but have it constantly changing after each iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to make a simple money adding program on python. I am trying to make it so that for the first iteration of the function changeCalculator() coin is set to 0.0. For the second iteration, I want coin set to 0.0 + whatever amount I chose. I then want the function to repeat until the user hits 'q'. My problem is that I cannot figure out how to set coin to 0.0 for only the first time, without setting it to 0.0 each iteration.

```
def changeCalculator():
    coin = 0.0                      
    coin = input()
    if coin == 'a':
        money = money + 20.0
        print(money)
        return money
    elif coin == 's':
        money = money + 10.0
        print(money)
        return money
    elif coin == 'd':
        money = money + 5.0
        print(money)
        return money
    elif coin == 'f':
        money = money + 1.0
        print(money)
        return money
    elif coin == 'g':
        money = money + 0.25
        print(money)
        return money
    elif coin == 'h':
        money = money + .10
        print(money)
        return money
    elif coin == 'j':
        money = money + .05
        print(money)
        return money
    elif coin == 'k':
        money = money + .01
        print(money)
        return money
    elif coin == 'q':
        return 'end'




print('This is a simple calculator to add money easily.')
print('a = 20$, s = $10, d = $5, f = $1, g = a quarter,')
print('h = a dime, j = a nickel, k = a penny.')
print('Hit q to quit.')
print('Hit the key and then enter to add money:')

while True:
    changeCalculator()
    `enter code here`if changeCalculator() != 'end':
        continue

cash = changeCalculator()
print(cash)
```

Comment: set `coin = 0` outside the while loop have the `changeCalculator` return the increment and increment coin by doing `coin += changeCalculator()`

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the money variable anywhere. Every iteration of the loop is calling the function which resets your `coin` to `0.0` and returns the money. Bring it outside the function. You could also use a dictionary to map the keys and their values.

```
keymap = {'a': 20,
         's': 10,
         'd': 5,
         'f': 1,
         'g': 0.25,
         'h': 0.1,
         'j': 0.05,
         'k': 0.01}

# Prompt user
print(*("press {} to add ${}".format(k,v) for k,v in keymap.items()),
      "press q to quit the program", sep="\n")

money = 0.
choice = input()
while choice != 'q':
    money += keymap[choice]
    choice = input()

print("Your total is ${}.".format(money))
```